# Undoing whitespace changes in Perforce

Tags: whitespace, perforce

Is there an easy way to undo whitespace changes in Perforce?

I have a .vimrc script that trims trailing whitespace on save, but in certain branches of code, the owner of said code doesn't want whitespace diffs.

I typically have to make a copy of my file, revert the original file, then manually integrate the non-whitespace changes I made.

Is there a simple command in Perforce (or other UNIX tools) that can do this automatically?

`p4 resolve` as a `-dw` option for ignoring whitespace, but I don't know how I'd make the file resolvable in the first place.

Comment: You obviously need a .vimrc script to introduce trailing whitespace! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming in this example your revision was `#4` and your file is `foo`:

```
p4 sync file#3
p4 edit file
p4 sync file
p4 resolve -dw
```

You can also do this across many files at the changelist level; sync back to previous change, open for edit, sync to your change, resolve with whatever options.

I *think* that when you do `resolve -dw` it keeps the "yours" version of whitespace-only diffs, which in this case will be `file#3` which is what you want.

Note that if you have individual lines with both whitespace and non-whitespace diffs you'll most likely get the whitespace diff along with the rest of the line since Perforce's merge operates per-line.  If all else fails, find another merge tool that'll do the specific thing you want to do with the whitespace, set `P4MERGE` to that, and do `p4 resolve`;`m`.

If your changes are still pending I think you can do something like:

```
p4 print -o depotRev file
p4 merge3 -dw depotRev file depotRev > merged
rm depotRev
```

then do:

```
diff file merged
```

to make sure the diffs look right before replacing your `file` with `merged`.

Comment: Ah, this sounds like the solution if I had submitted my change already, right? Is it possible to resolve a non-submitted file against what's in depot?

Comment: Perforce only sets up a resolve when there's something in the depot that's not included in your file; I can't think of a way to "trick" it into thinking that's the case in such a way as to get the result you want here.  You'll want to just run a merge tool manually -- `p4 merge3` is one option (outlined above), or you could use `diff3` or `p4merge` etc.

Comment: Note also that if this policy only applies to "certain branches of code", an easy solution is to make sure that when you integrate into those branches you use the `-dw` option on THAT resolve.  :)